# Why can't I send a message to the multicast address, if the socket is bound to 0.0.0.0. for ipv6 socket it works

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, ipv6, ipv4

I have the two sockets to send a message to multicast, ipv6 and ipv4

For ipv6 method works correctly

For the ipv4 it does not work, if the socket is not bound to a direct address.

Why should I specify the address to create a socket

**IPV6:**

```
    private static void SendToMulticastIpv6()
    {
        var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, 10);
        socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new IPv6MulticastOption(IPAddress.Parse("ff02::c")));

        socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.IPv6Any, 0));

        socket.SendTo(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("message"), new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("ff02::c"), 1900));

        Console.WriteLine("done v6");
    }
```

**IPV4:**

```
    private static void SendToMulticastIpv4()
    {
        var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, 10);
        socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership,
            new MulticastOption(IPAddress.Parse("239.255.255.250")));

        //Does not works
        //socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0));

        //I need to specify the my address
        socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.100.100"), 0));

        socket.SendTo(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("message"), new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("239.255.255.250"), 1900));

        Console.WriteLine("done v4");
    }
```

Comment: FYI, your IPv6 multicast group and port is for Link-Local SSDP, but the IPv4 address is not; it is for Organization-Local Scope multicast addresses. The IPv4 multicast address for SSDP scoped addresses, e.g. `239.255.255.5` is for experimental only: "_It is only appropriate to use these values in explicitly-
configured experiments; they MUST NOT be shipped as defaults in
implementations._" See IANA's _[IPv4 Multicast Address Space Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml#multicast-addresses-13)_.

Comment: Oh, you are right, I'm interested in ssdp, when I tried to send to ipv6 organization-local(ff08::c), without binding the address, it also did not work.

Comment: but still, why to send a message to the multicast, I must bind the socket to specific address, and it can't be INADDR_ANY. I don't want to read the messages, i want only send

Comment: Since this is a Link-Local IPv6 multicast, you must specify the link on which it should be multicast. You cannot specify all links, which you seem to want to do. You may want to listen to all links, but you should only send on a single link.

Comment: @RonMaupin ok, I understood, ty